# Disable specific drop downs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that contains, let's say 10 drop downs. Currently all of the dropdowns are being disabled using the following jQuery:

```js
$('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"], input[type="textarea"], input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], select').prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

I need to disable only some of the dropdowns using this same statement. I know their IDs I'm just struggling with how to syntactically add them into this existing statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"], input[type="textarea"], input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], select','#myid1','#myid2').prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

Simply add them to the list of items with their id. I added them using fake id myid1 and myid2 so replace them with valid ids

Comment: Ok. so no parenthesis needed around each id?